# Multiple providers in multiple Symfony 2 firewall: how to avoid route conflicts?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having a small problem with firewalls routes conflicting. I expected Symfony to handle them in order, but it's not:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        first_area:
            pattern:    ^api/
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"
                provider: in_memory
        second_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"
                provider: in_database
```

This is conflicting, so i can't separate areas to have different providers.

Comment: Can you provide some ULR examples and what you're expecting from them? Because Koc answer could be a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `pattern:    ^/api/` for first firewall (added slash)